# How to get group name in data.table's group by?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to apply a function to a data.table's column but I want to take into account on what group the function is being applied i.e. I want to pass the group value as a parameter to the function. However I cannot get the group's name when my function is applied.

How to get the group value? Or should I be using a different approach?

Example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(369)
dta <- data.table(gr = 1:5, 
                  a = rnorm(5),  
                  b = rnorm(5),
                  c = rnorm(5),
                  d = rnorm(5))

add <- function(x, y, group){ 
  if(group == 1){
    x + y
  } else{
    x - y
  }
}

dta[, newcol := add(c, d), by = (gr)]
```

I can't figure out how to pass current group's value to the function

Comment: this is the purpose of the .BY symbol in data.table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Note1: My quick draw answer erroneously suggested using `.GRP`, which happens to return the same answer in this specific example. Per @MichaelChirico 's recommendation, `.BY` is the proper special symbol to use.*
>
> *Note 2: Thanks @Frank for the additional feedback -- I created a quick [gist here](https://gist.github.com/msummersgill/0972314d757324dc5d70968256bd62ea) of some experimentation with `.BY`, and have updated the answer again to properly reflect the need to reference the grouping columns in the list by name.*

Looks like the special symbol `.BY` is exactly what you're after. To learn more about how `.BY` and the other symbols work, run `help("special-symbols")` in the console to see the documentation.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(369)
dta <- data.table(gr = 1:5, 
                  a = rnorm(5),  
                  b = rnorm(5),
                  c = rnorm(5),
                  d = rnorm(5))

add <- function(x, y, group){ 
  if(group == 1){
    x + y
  } else{
    x - y
  }
}

dta[, newcol := add(c, d, .BY$gr), by = (gr)]

print(dta)

#    gr          a           b           c            d     newcol
# 1:  1 -0.7506434  1.08042639 -0.57234502 -0.009598695 -0.5819437
# 2:  2  0.8976528 -0.45909601 -0.08179559 -1.359655922  1.2778603
# 3:  3  0.7449628 -0.92638505 -1.11577747  0.654088229 -1.7698657
# 4:  4  0.5811869 -0.07451776 -0.50771981 -1.009298251  0.5015784
# 5:  5 -0.3270194  0.97218850  0.55705663 -0.032128474  0.5891851
```

> *Note 3: This also works just fine for most use cases and might be a little bit more intuitive:*

```
dta[, newcol := add(c, d, gr), by = (gr)]
```

Comment: .BY is a list, but happens to work for the OP's case since list(1) == 1. You could do `add(c, d, .BY$gr)` or more generally but less readably `do.call(add, c(list(c, d), .BY))` provided the names match.

Comment: Thanks @Frank -- Messing around with some other cases in a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/msummersgill/0972314d757324dc5d70968256bd62ea) I see there's more layers to the onion than I'd pulled back before, and I see what you're saying about the `.BY$gr` recommendation. I'd definitely welcome any other feedback to make sure I'm not spreading disinformation here.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess the point is not so much that they must be referenced by name as that you usually need to access one element of `.BY` rather than the full list, for example, `dta[, sqrt(.BY), by=gr]` fails because you can't take the sqrt of a list, so `dta[, sqrt(.BY$gr), by=gr]` or `dta[, sqrt(.BY[[1]]), by=gr]`. Actually, you can just refer to `gr` directly and do not need to go through `.BY` like `dta[, sqrt(gr), by=gr]`. Sorry for the confusion; the latter would be my recommendation, I guess. Now I'm wondering why the OP didn't try that initially :)

Comment: Yup. I took a step back as well and realized that `dta[, sqrt(gr), by=gr]` is the way that I probably would have gone about this normally -- now I'm just trying to figure out if there are any cases where that wouldn't work. I think it might present some problems with multiple grouping variables and more observations per group? Surely there have to be some, otherwise why is the `.BY` special symbol necessary?

Comment: There are a couple reasons I use it: to make my code more readable (in the sense that I can clearly see that I'm using a grouping variable), to make it agnostic with respect to .BY vars (eg, with toString(.BY) as a plot title or `cat`-ed to console when `j` is slow so I can track progress). Here's one example: http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html (search for .BY) Also, it can be useful to pass arguments in the do.call pattern I mentioned, I think.